# TypeScript async type guard using Promise

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, types

I'm trying to define an asynchronous type guard. I can do the following synchronously:

```
class Foo {
    public type = 'Foo';
}

// Sync type guard:
function isFoo(obj: any): obj is Foo {
    return typeof obj.type !== 'undefined' && obj.type === 'Foo';
}

function useFoo(foo: Foo): void {
    alert(`It's a Foo!`);
}

const a: object = new Foo();
if (isFoo(a)) useFoo(a);
```

But I'm not sure how to do the same async. This is what I tried:

```
class Bar {
    public getType = () => new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve('Bar'), 1000);
    });
}

// Async type guard:
async function isBar(obj: any): Promise<obj is Bar> {
    if (typeof obj.getType === 'undefined') return false;
    const result = await obj.getType();
    return result === 'Bar';
}

function useBar(bar: Bar): void {
    alert(`It's a Bar!`);
}

const b: object = new Bar();
isBar(b).then(bIsBar => {
    if (bIsBar) useBar(b);
});
```

[Try it here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Bar%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getType%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20new%20Promise(resolve%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20resolve('Bar')%2C%201000)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Async%20type%20guard%3A%0D%0Aasync%20function%20isBar(obj%3A%20any)%3A%20Promise%3Cobj%20is%20Foo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20obj.getType%20%3D%3D%3D%20'undefined')%20return%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20await%20obj.getType()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result%20%3D%3D%3D%20'Bar'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20useBar(bar%3A%20Bar)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20alert(%60It's%20a%20Bar!%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20new%20Bar()%3B%0D%0AisBar(b).then(bIsBar%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(bIsBar)%20useBar(b)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems it is not a feature yet. Maybe you could [submit the idea](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues)?

Comment: This seems to work fine when targeting es6 using tsc 2.0.9 and node 7.7.3.

Comment: See [Issue #37681 **Asynchronous type guards and assertion signatures**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681) in the TypeScript bug tracker. Maybe one of the workarounds applies to your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't access the guarded parameter from outside the direct scope of the function.  So once you return a promise, you can't guard `obj` anymore.  This sounds like a neat feature idea, and as @Paleo suggests you should maybe submit it if there isn't one already.

It might not help though; even if you could *express* a type guard across scopes, the compiler might widen the type again since there's a chance the value could mutate:

```
class Bar {
  public getType = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('Bar'), 1000);
  });
  public barProp: string; // added to distinguish structurally from NotBar
}

class NotBar {
  public getType = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('NotBar'), 1000);
  });
  public notBarProp: string; // added to distinguish structurally from Bar
}

function useBar(bar: Bar): void {
  alert(`It's a Bar!`);
}

function useNotBar(notBar: NotBar): void {
  alert(`Nope, not a Bar.`)
}

var b: Bar | NotBar = new Bar();

if (b instanceof Bar) {
  useBar(b); // narrowed to Bar, no error
  isBar(b).then(bIsBar => {        
    useBar(b); // error! widened to Bar | NotBar again
  })
}
```

As a possible workaround, you can invent your own "type guard" object and pass that back, although it's not as pleasant to use:

```
type Guarded<Y, N = any> = { matches: true, value: Y } | { matches: false, value: N };
function guarded<Y, N = any>(v: Y | N, matches: boolean): Guarded<Y, N> {
  return matches ? { matches: true, value: <Y>v } : { matches: false, value: <N>v };
}

// Async type guard:
async function isBar<N extends { getType?: () => Promise<any> } = any>(obj: Bar | N): Promise<Guarded<Bar, N>> {
  if (typeof obj.getType === 'undefined') return guarded(obj, false);
  const result = await obj.getType();
  return guarded(obj, result === 'Bar');
}

isBar(b).then(bIsBar => {
  if (bIsBar.matches) useBar(bIsBar.value);
});

isBar<NotBar>(b).then(bIsBar => {
  if (bIsBar.matches) useBar(bIsBar.value); else useNotBar(bIsBar.value);
});
```

Comment: See [Issue #37681 **Asynchronous type guards and assertion signatures**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37681) in the TypeScript bug tracker. Maybe one of the workarounds there also applies to the needs for an async guard?